# How To Call A Controller Method From Isolate Scope Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

What I'm doing wrong?

After of the click on "Click me" text in status block should appear a new string. (actually 4 new lines, but there are only 2)

[(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/aleksey_danchina/5RBea/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <button my-directive status="status" clickHandler="handler(message)">Click me</button>
        <pre>{{ status }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$timeout',
    function myController ($scope, $timeout) {

        $scope.status = 'Start controller.\n'; // update status
        $scope.someData = 'Hello from controller !!!\n';
        $scope.handler = function handler (message) {
            $scope.status += $scope.someData; // must update status, but doesn't do it
            $scope.status += 'Message from directive: ' + message; // must too
        }

    }]);

app.directive('myDirective', function myDirective () {
    return {
        scope: { clickHandler: '&', status: '=' },
        link: function postLink (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.status += 'Start link in myDirective.\n'; // update status
            element.on('click', function onClick (event) {
                scope.status += 'Click is fired.\n'; // update status
                scope.$apply(function scopeApply () {
                    scope.status += 'In apply context.\n'; // update status
                    scope.clickHandler('"I\'m from directive."\n');
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML

The attribute name should be dash-separated:

```
<button my-directive status="status" click-handler="handler(message)">
    Click me
</button>
```

### JS

The method should be called by passing in an object:

```
scope.clickHandler({message:'"I\'m from directive."\n'});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RBea/9/)**